# Add bold, italize or underline to be a part of a style in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I am trying to create a new style in Word, say 'My style'. But when I bold, italize or underline a word or sentence in that style, it appears as a new style 'My style (with para space) + Bold'. Is there any way to include them as part of a style so that it appears as 'My style' itself even if we bold or italize a word in that style.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've seen that done in some documents but I have not idea how

Comment: You say 'include it as part of your style'. What do you mean? as far as I know you can't select text by the style applied, so what does it matter?

Comment: @djsmiley2k you can select a text and apply a style but if you want to make any formatting changes to that text, it comes up as a new style. It doesn't matter visually but when you're creating a template, it messes up your styles creating a lot of styles for every formatting change.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it. In style pane options, unchecking 'Select formatting to show as styles' will stop every formatting changes being made to come up as a new style.

[image: Screenshot can be viewed here]

Comment: This is the right answer for the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for this. The quickest and, I feel, messiest is to highlight the text in Word and rightclick on the style and select "Update style to match selection". This will update all the text using that format.

Alternatively you can create a new style.

1. Click the little expansion arrow on the styles box.

[image]

2. Click Add New Style

[image]

3. Choose the style you want to base your new style off and click OK
4. In the popup dialog box, click the **bold** icon then click OK

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I'm not updating the style to be bold. Maybe I was not explaining myself right. I have created a style that is not bold named 'My style'. Now I want to bold one word in a sentence that is using 'My style'. When I do that a new style 'My style (with para space) + Bold' is created.